# Highlightning active nested states with Angular UI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The hierarchy in my application looks like this

```
Project (URL: /project)
  |- Module 1 (URL: /project/module1)
  |- Module 2 (URL: /project/module2)
  |- Settings (URL: /project/settings)
    |-- General Settings (Default view) (URL: /project/settings)
    |-- Module settings (URL: /project/settings/modules)
```

Hence this is what my routes for settings look like (`cofeescript`)

```
    .state 'project-details.settings', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/settings',
      templateUrl: 'settings.html'
    }
    .state 'project-details.settings.general', {
      url: '',
      templateUrl: 'templates/projects/settings/general.html'
    }
    .state 'project-details.settings.contributors', {
      url: '/contributors',
      templateUrl: 'contributors.html'
    }
    # more routes...
```

My project navigation looks like this

Module 1
      Settings

Clicking on the `Settings` link highlights the link as expected. But leaving the `/project/settings` route and navigating to a sub route (e.g. `/project/settings/modules`) "un-highlights" the link.

There's an additional navigation within the settings state itself, which is also highlighted;

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="project-details.settings.general">General</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="project-details.settings.modules">Modules</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Highlightning here works fine.

I've tried to put the general settings within the `/settings` route (by putting the template in the `ui-view` tags) and getting rid of the `general` route. The "outer" navigation highlightning worked - but the inner one was messed up, since "General" was highlighted all the time.

Summarized: I want my settings (`/project/settings`) to be highlighted when you're in the settings, no matter what child state (`/project/settings/...`). The settings navigation should just highlight the active settings state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your architecture is consistent, you can implement a function to check a specific part of it:

**Function**:

```
$scope.isNavActive = function (path)
{
  try
  {
    return ($location.path ().split ('/')[2] === path.split ('/')[2]);
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    return false;
  }
};
```

**Usage**:

```
<li ng-class="{active: isNavActive ('/Project/Settings')}">
  <a href="/Project/Settings/Modules"
    Modules
  </a>
</li>
```

Of course, if you're looking for more complicated logic you can do that, but the key is to assess your needs and implement the minimal reasonable solution to try and reduce overhead. If your function is too complex your page might slow down if it runs on every digest cycle.

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks!